# Two separate if clauses or one single if else

Tags: if-statement

Stupid question, is it a good practice to use two separate if clauses or one single if with if else clause, eg:

```
if (a = 1)
(dosomething)
if (a=2)
(do other thing)
```

OR

```
if (a=1)
(do something)
else if (a=2)
(do other thing)
```

Those two if conditions ARE NOT true the same time. Variable a is used as comparator and not changed at all.

The two ways work as expected and nothing programmatically wrong with it, I am just asking what is a good practice and recommended?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd use the style that is easier for you to read.
Clarity is always better than difficult to follow code.

Execution speed isn't going to be a big problem here.

Answer (score 4):

Depends on what you want to achieve.

In the first case **both** conditions will be evaluated, as being independent - even both conditions are *true*.

In the second case, if the first condition is evaluated as *true*, the *else-if* branch will be skipped.

You can see a full explanation on [JLS](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.9).

Comment: how both conditions will be evaluated in first case?

Comment: first one : if (a = 1) and the second one : if (a=2). (one after each other)

Comment: at a time how can a be equal to 1 as well as 2?

Comment: You miss the entire idea. I'm not saying that a is equal to 1 and 2 in the same time, I am saying that both conditions will be evaluated.

Comment: ah, got it...it will check every condition inspite one condition being evaluated....sorry

Comment: @loan: I am just asking what is a good practice in this case, of course both ways work but what is recommended?

Comment: As Daniel Daranas said in his answer : You cannot talk about best practice between two things which mean different things. What do you want to achieve? - this is the question which should help you decide.

Comment: @loan: In my case, similar as in my example, the two conditions DO NOT happen the same time and the checked variable does not change, so it can be put separately in two if clauses and also in if and if else clause, but which one is recommended?

Comment: Then the second approach would be better.

Comment: @Maluvel which one ?

Comment: @loan the one from foxidrive

Answer (score 2):

If you use the first way, every single if-statement is checked. In the second way, all the following else cases are ignored, if one was correct.

So if there are a complex if-conditions it could take a lot longer in way 1.

By checking such values (a == 1, a == 2, a == 3,...), try switch!

Answer (score 2):

Those two tests are distinctly different. In the first case, if at first `a` is 1 and `do something` changes the value of `a` to 2, then `do other thing` will also be executed. This is not the case in the second variant. So which one to use depends on what you want to acheive.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you mean. If you want the second condition to be tested only if the first is not true, use `if (...) else if (...)` option. Instead if you want both conditions to be checked independently, use `if (...) if (...)`.

One cannot talk about best practice between two things which mean different things. Just write in each case what the algorithm you designed tells you to write, i.e., faithfully express your design in the code.

Comment: In my case, similar as in my example, the two conditions DO NOT happen the same time and the checked variable does not change, so it can be put separately in two if clauses and also in if and if else clause, but which one is recommended?

Comment: @Maluvel There is no official recommendation from a "recommendations comitee". Just do what you like. _I_ would choose if (...) else if (...) to better express that I am talking about mutually exclusive possibilities.

Answer (score 1):

If the conditions are mutually exclusive (only one can be in same time), second way. Else, if both conditions can happen at same time, first way is the right.

Answer (score 0):

At least in Java bytecode, there are three different scenarios:

### If-else

```java
if(a == 3)  // load an int from local variable a, load int value 3 onto the stack
            // if they are not equal go (branch) to line a = 4;
    a = 5;  // load int value 5 onto the stack, save it into the variable
else        // there's no instruction for this line as it's behavior was
            // described in line if(a == 3)
    a = 4;  // load int value 4 onto the stack, save it into the variable
```

### If-else-if

```java
if(a == 3)      // load an int from local variable a, load int value 3 onto the
                // stack, if they are not equal go (branch) to line if(a != 3)
    a = 5;      // load int value 5 onto the stack, save it into the variable
                // go to line after a = 4;
else if(a != 3) // load an int from local variable a, load int value 3 onto the
                // stack, if they are equal go (branch) to line after a = 4;
    a = 4;      // load int value 4 onto the stack, save it into the variable
```

### If-if

```java
if(a == 3)  // load an int from local variable a, load int value 3 onto the stack
            // if they are not equal go (branch) to line if(a != 3)
    a = 5;  // load int value 5 onto the stack, save it into the variable
if(a != 3)  // load an int from local variable a, load int value 3 onto the stack
            // if they are equal go (branch) to line after a = 4;
    a = 4;  // load int value 4 onto the stack, save it into the variable
```

### Example code

```java
int a = 5;

int ifelse()
{
    if(a == 5)  a = 3;  // true, go to return
    else        a = 6;

    return a;           // returns 3
}

int ifelseif()
{
    if(a == 2)      a = 3;  // false, go to next line
    else if(a == 3) a = 6;  // false, go to next line
    else if(a == 5) a = 9;  // true go to return

    return a;               // returns 9 (btw you might use switch for this)
}

int ifif()
{
    if(a == 5)  a = 3;  // true, go to next line
    if(a == 3)  a = 6;  // true, go to return

    return a;           // returns 6
}
```

### Long story short

- If-else – compares once, one thing happens
- If-else-if – compares once or twice depending on results, nothing or one thing happens, use for nesting if-clauses
- If-if – compares twice, nothing, one or two things happen